# Book about a boy named Milo who loses his eyebrows and runs away

Tags: identification-request

I read this book around 14 years ago. All I can remember about the story is that it was about a boy named Milo, who ends up losing his eyebrows and running away from home — the overall plot, from memory, was that he somehow ends up visiting a place where monsters come down from space. I can't remember whether he's tasked with saving the world or similar.